# EclipseLink: Map of key to entity where the PK of the entity is the key in the map

Tags: java, eclipselink

What I am looking to do is have the primary key for Object3 entity contain both its parent Object1(@ManyToOne) and the Object2 that is the key in the map that the Object3 is paired with in the Object1 (property1).  Is this possible to do with EclipseLink, perhaps with an annotation?

I hope that made sense, to summarize: The PK of Object3 is (Object1,Object2)

```
@Entity
public class Object1{
  ...
  private Map<Object2,Object3> property1;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Object3{
  @Column(name = "c1")
  private int number;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "Object1")
  private Object1 object1;
  ...
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way - what are you going to pass to em.find and obtain a particular Object3 instance? Object3 needs mappings to all its foreign key fields to use for its primary key or it isn't an independent entity.  Something like:

```
  @Entity
  @IdClass(Object3PK.class)
  public class Object3{
    @Column(name = "c1")
    private int number;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Object1")
    private Object1 object1;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Object2")
    private Object2 object2;
    ...
  }

  public class Object3PK{
     private int object1;
     private int object2;
  }
```

In the above, Object3PK must use the same types as the primary keys within Object1 and Object2.  This is described [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#JPA_2.0)

In Object1 then, you can use a standard OneToMany mapping that points to the Object1 ManyToOne mapping back.  The only part missing is a [MapKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKey.html) :

```
  @Entity
  public class Object1{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="object1")
    @MapKey(name="object2")
    private Map<Object2,Object3> property1;
    ...
  }
```